# Swift Compiler Error: read_user_chunkIDOT:1062: invalid PNG file: no valid iEnd chunk

Tags: swift, xcode, image, debugging, png

Without having changed absolutely anything, just after a cleaning, the debugger started prompting this weird message, and a black square appears in a part of the app that is not related to any image. Moreover, when I open the view hierarchy to debug, there is no black square anywhere and everything looks fine. There is no indication at all of what png file is causing the problem, and that black square does not correspond to any imageView or UIView! I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

The problem came indeed from a png file that was being loaded on storyBoard. What threw me off was these three combined facts: 
1) The problem started to happen all of a sudden without me having touched the storyboard or even less that particular image. 
2) The black square that was supposed to be in place of the "missing image" was not of the size of the image, and its size was different in the two viewControllers where the image was used, thus making it even harder for me to guess what image was supposed to be in that place.
3) The image is a very subtle gradient whose slightly darker part was approximately what the black square only covered.